# Including external js with requirejs

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I have the following in my js file that is called by requirejs

```
    define([
      'jquery',
      'backbone',
      'mobiledetect'
    ],
 function($, Backbone, mobiledetect) {
  var MobileCheckView = Backbone.View.extend({
     initialize: function(){
     var md = new MobileDetect(window.navigator.userAgent);
     if (md.mobile() || md.phone() || md.tablet()) {
        $('#mho_app').popup('show');
     } 
     }
    });
     return MobileCheckView;
    });
```

I get Uncaught ReferenceError: MobileDetect is not defined when referencing the external file via path in my main.js file

I have tried defining it directly at the top of the file as well with no luck. What am I missing that's keeping the script from loading and giving me the object?

```
    define('mobiledetect', ['https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mobile-detect/1.3.6/mobile-detect.min.js'], function () {
       var md = new MobileDetect(window.navigator.userAgent);
       return md;
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the [paths](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-paths) configuration in RequireJS to set mobiledetect to the URL, like so.  Note that the ".js" is left off of the URL.  RequireJS will automatically add the ".js" extension.

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    'mobiledetect': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mobile-detect/1.3.6/mobile-detect.min'
  }
});
require(['mobiledetect'], function (MobileDetect) {
  var md = new MobileDetect(window.navigator.userAgent);
  if (md.mobile() || md.phone() || md.tablet()) {
    alert('Mobile Device');
  }
  else {
    alert('Must be a desktop?');
  }
});
```

See this [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/erbronni/khpzmoko/) to see the code in action.  You will get an alert stating whether you are on a mobile or desktop browser.

Also, the parameter `mobiledetect` should be `MobileDetect` to match the `new MobileDetect` call.

Comment: require(['mobiledetect'], function (MobileDetect) looks like the piece I needed. I did add paths in require.config in the main js file so I think I had that part right. Gotta try this on Monday, but this looks like it does the trick. Thanks.